# importing cx_Oracle and kinterbasdb returns error

Tags: python, cx-oracle, kinterbasdb

Greetings, everybody.

I'm trying to import the following libraries in python: cx_Oracle and kinterbasdb.

But, when I try, I get a very similar message error.
*for cx_Oracle:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: DLL load failed: Não foi possível encontrar o procedimento especificado.
(translation: It was not possible to find the specified procedure)

*for kinterbasdb:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\", line 1, in 
  File "c:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\kinterbasdb__init__.py", line 119, in 
    import _kinterbasdb as _k
ImportError: DLL load failed: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
(translation: It was not possible to find the specified procedure)

I'm using python 2.6.4 in windows XP. cx_Oracle's version is 5.0.2. kinterbasdb's version is 3.3.0.

Edit: I've solved it for cx_Oracle, it was a wrong version problem. But I believe I'm using the correct version, and I downloaded it from the Firebird site ( kinterbasdb-3.3.0.win32-setup-py2.6.exe ). Still need assistance with this, please.

Can anyone lend me a hand here?
Many Thanks
Dante

Answer (score -1):

oracle is a complete pain.  i don't know the details for windows, but for unix you need ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to both be defined before cx_oracle will work.  in windows this would be your environment variables, i guess.  so check those.

also, check that they are defined in the environment in which the program runs (again, i don't know windows specific details, but in unix it's possible for everything to work when you run it from your account by hand, but still not work when run as a batch job because the environment is different).